# AWS Cloudwatch trigger Codepipeline on dynamic tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I want to tag a commit with dynamic tag, for example `git tag deploy-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")`, and then trigger codepipeline from cloudwatch. The problem is if I use following cloudwatch event pattern:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.codecommit"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeCommit Repository State Change"
  ],
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:codecommit:region:XXX:someName"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "event": [
      "referenceCreated",
      "referenceUpdated"
    ],
    "repositoryName": [
      "someName"
    ],
    "referenceType": [
      "tag"
    ],
    "referenceName": [
      "deploy"
    ]
  }
}
```

it will be triggered only on specific tag - "deploy". Is there a way to say any tag that starts with(contains) deploy keyword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking at the [Content-based Filtering with Event Patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html) docs and its [Prefix Matching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html#filtering-prefix-matching). The example given in the docs is:

```
{
  "time": [ { "prefix": "2017-10-02" } ],
}
```

Based on the example, the following seems as it could work in your case:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.codecommit"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeCommit Repository State Change"
  ],
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:codecommit:region:XXX:someName"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "event": [
      "referenceCreated",
      "referenceUpdated"
    ],
    "repositoryName": [
      "someName"
    ],
    "referenceType": [
      "tag"
    ],
    "referenceName": [
       { "prefix": "deploy" } ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately it's not working. I already tried this way and I get error "Validation error.
Details: Event pattern contains invalid element (can only be Strings enclosed in quotes, numbers, and the unquoted keywords true, false, and null)"

Comment: @datahack Could you check please in the EventBridge Console, not CloudWatch Events. I had no problems there creating such a rule. I didn't check its functionality, but EB does not complain about the rule with `{ "prefix": "deploy" }`.

Comment: Ok now i'm really confused. AWS states following: "Amazon EventBridge (formerly CloudWatch Events) provides all functionality from CloudWatch Events...". I did not expect new service console :) I will try and let you know if its working. Thank you!

Comment: @datahack No problem. Check how it works and let me know it will go please.

Comment: Working! Thanks!

Comment: @datahack Glad to hear that:-)

Comment: @Marcin can we adjust the EventBridge such that it triggers pipeline  when a matching string appears on suffix.  I am planning to trigger the pipeline when it is tagged in the format  v0.0.2-develop
V0.0.2-staging
v0.0.2-product

Comment: @sandeepkrishna Not sure now.  I think you could ask new question with relevant details.

Comment: @Marcin There is an extra bracket in line `"deploy" } ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard in the prefix:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.codecommit"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "CodeCommit Repository State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "referenceType": [
      "tag"
    ],
    "referenceName": [
      {
        "prefix": "deploy-*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @shariqmaws thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this is not working. You can not use prefix like this, cloudwatch event produces error - "Event pattern contains invalid element"

Comment: Remove *,  ie prefix": "deploy"